# Why is sync so important when making a bootable linux usb stick?

Tags: dd, storage, bootable, removable-storage

From the Arch Linux Wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media

> `# dd bs=4M if=/path/to/archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress && sync`
>
> [...] Do **not** miss sync to complete before pulling the USB drive.

I would like to know

- What does it do?
- What consequences are there if left out?

---

## Notes

`dd` command used with optional `status=progress`:

```
tar -xzOf archlinux-2016-09-03-dual.iso | dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=4M status=progress && sync
```

Or using `pv` for progress

```
tar -xzOf archlinux-2016-09-03-dual.iso | pv | dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=4M && sync
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `dd` does not bypass the kernel disk caches when it writes to a device, so  some part of data may be not written yet to the `USB` stick upon `dd` completion. If you unplug your `USB` stick at that moment, the content on the `USB` stick would be inconsistent. Thus, your system could even fail to boot from this `USB` stick.

`Sync` flushes any still-in-cache data to the device.

Instead of invoking `sync` you could use `fdatasync` `dd`'s conversion option:

> fdatasync
>
> physically write output file data before finishing

In your case, the command would be:

```
tar -xzOf archlinux-2016-09-03-dual.iso | \
dd of=/dev/disk2 bs=4M status=progress conv=fdatasync
```

The `conv=fdatasync` makes `dd` effectively call `fdatasync()` system call at the end of transfer just before `dd` exits (I checked this with `dd`'s sources).

This confirms that `dd` would not bypass nor flush the caches unless explicitly instructed to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, however I am not sure that this statement is correct *The `dd` does not bypass the kernel disk caches when it writes to a device*. When writing to a file (over the file system layer of the kernel), things are cached. However, I am concerned about writing to devices. Please provide a source for that statement if you can, because that is the linchpin of this question. If true, it would provide a valid reason for running `sync` after a **`dd`-to-device** operation.

Comment: Yes it is cached. The caching happens inside block device infrastructure of the kernel. The file operations itself are not cached. the underlying block device interface does cashing. source: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/blk-flush.c

Comment: @macmadness86 see the updated answer

Comment: I preffer using `oflag=sync`, so progress outputs the real transfer speed and not the cached one (so going a steady 10MB/s instead of one second 100MB/s and then 10 seconds of stall).

Comment: Writing to a block device bypasses VFS altogether. In other words: writing to a file can be cached by the kernel (and it usually is) but writing to a device is never cached by the kernel (and it can't).

Comment: @Eric That is definitely not correct. See, for example, the citation by Serge into the Linux kernel source code. (Which,updated to fix the dead link is: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/block/blk-flush.c)

Comment: @Keely Hoek the code you pointed out is not part of VFS. I said that when you open a device you bypass VFS. System calls like read() and write() are directly handled by the device driver, not the VFS layer. And so theVFS layer is basically unable to cache anything since it's not being involved.

Comment: @Serge i would really appreciate if you can also mention `conv=fsync` in your answer and explain why you rather use/recommend one or the other.

Comment: The [Arch USB flash medium](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/USB_flash_installation_medium) guide now uses the options `oflag=direct conv=fsync`. `fsync` does the same as `fdatasync` and and additionally syncs file metadata like `st_atime`, `st_mtime` (again no need for an explicit call to `sync` after running `dd`). The explanation of `oflag=direct` leaves much to be desired in `man dd`, but `info dd` explains that it uses "[..] direct I/O for data, avoiding the buffer cache.".

Comment: @JonathanKomar, @DJCrashdummy, yes, that's why both options have absolutely the same effect when we are writing directly to a block device: there is no fs metadata to sync. As for `oflag=direct` - it's interesting, I will check...

Comment: @Serge Any update with `oflag=direct`?

Answer (score 1):

From the sync(1) manual page : "sync - Synchronize cached writes to persistent storage". Basically `sync` makes sure that all your data is written to the stick from the cache.

Comment: I don't see where in your question appears the part about the light being up.