# Which method prefer to create bootable usb using dd?

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, system-installation, usb-drive, bootable

This [USB flash installation media](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media#In_GNU.2FLinux) guides me to use `oflag=sync`:

```
# dd bs=4M if=/path/to/archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress oflag=sync
```

... but other articles like [itsfoss](https://itsfoss.com/install-arch-linux/) guide me to use `sync`:

```
# dd bs=4M if=/path/to/archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress && sync
```

Which one is preferred: the `oflag=sync` option to dd, or a separate `sync` command?

Comment: I prefer using the separate `sync` command, because you won't need to sync the write if it fails. The `&&` separator makes sure `sync` is only run if the `dd` command completes successfully.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/312687/34720) should partially answer your question. Basically, `dd` does not bypasses kernel disk caches when writing to device, and using this `oflag` will sync those disk writes to disk.

Both `sync` command  and `oflag=sync` will do the same job. The only difference i can spot here is that [`sync`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sync) command will write to disk all caches from all disks so, a machine that is pretty busy writing to other disks will have a slower(you may even not feel it) response.

Quoting `sync` documentation:

> **Description**
>
> sync writes ***any data buffered in memory out to disk***. This
>   can include (but is not limited to) modified superblocks, modified
>   inodes, and delayed reads and writes. This must be implemented by the
>   kernel; The sync program does nothing but exercise the [`sync(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sync) system
>   call.