# Burning a Linux Ubuntu bootable USB with dd

Tags: ubuntu, osx, usb, dd, bootable

I am installing Linux on a machine and got [the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS image](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). I formatted a 32 GB Sandisk drive on macOS with MS-DOS (FAT) format and GUID Partition Map scheme.

I found the name of the disk as `disk2s2` (either with Disk Utility or `diskutil list` in Terminal), unmounted and copied the image with `dd` following [these instructions](http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/05/copy-iso-to-usb-drive-mac-os-x-command/):

```bsh
diskutil unmount /dev/disk2s2
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/rdisk2s2 bs=1m
```

I inserted the USB on the Dell machine, booted, pressed F12 to go into "Boot Once" menu, chose legacy boot with USB, and got

```
Selected boot device failed. Press any key to reboot the system.
```

When I follow [the instructions from Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#3) and flash the ISO image on the USB with [Etcher](https://etcher.io/), it works and I see an extra option in "Boot Once": `UEFI SanDisk, Partition 1`, which I chose and was able to try Linux.

What else do I need to create a bootable USB of Ubuntu with `dd`, or all in the command line?

Comment: Did you use `sync` after `dd` ? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312687/why-is-sync-so-important-when-making-a-bootable-linux-usb-stick

Comment: No, I didn't. I used the same command with `sync` at the end but I still do not see the drive in `Boot Once` mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've made a mistake in where you write the image to.

The disk image contains a partition table of it's own so you need to write the image to the disk, not to a partition.

The *partition* is mounted as `disk2s2` so you do need to `diskutil unmount /dev/disk2s2` that.  You should ensure that no other partitions on the USB drive are mounted as well.   Use `diskutil list` to get the full list of partitions and make sure you have unmounted *all* partitions on the USB drive.

You then need to overwrite the entire disk (all partitions) with the ubuntu image.

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m
```

Note here the *partition* is called `/dev/disk2s2` but the USB *disk* is called `/dev/disk2`

I'm less familiar with macs, but if there is a `sync` command, you should use it before removing the drive. See [Why is sync so important when making a bootable linux usb stick?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312687/why-is-sync-so-important-when-making-a-bootable-linux-usb-stick)

Comment: This was the right command, thank you. It took 3 times longer than the command in my question. I tried without `&& sync` at the end out of curiosity and it worked, though I understand it's best practice to add it. I also think that the step of formatting the drive as MS-FAT is unnecessary, since the drive then appears on macOS as Apple HFS.

Comment: @mmorin Absolutely.  You don't need to format it or change it in any way.  Just plug it in, ensure it's not mounted then `dd` to it.