# Has 'sync' been proved to be necessary when writing to a block device with 'dd'?

Tags: linux, dd, cache, block-device, synchronization

Every time I've written a file to an empty raw block device, e.g.

```
# dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdb status=progress
```

I've never used any type of `sync` (i.e. `sync`; `conv=fsync`; `conv=fdatasync`; `oflag=sync`; `oflag=dsync`).

I've noticed that `dd` doesn't ***ever*** exit until all writing has finished.

I always verify this using Conky's I/O facility and `grep Dirty /proc/meminfo`. Also, the checksum of the device always matches that of the file that was written to it. So I am always 100% sure that the whole file was written to the device.

I've written files to an ext4 volume to compare. For example using:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=~/file bs=1M count=50 iflag=fullblock
```

When writing to an ext4 volume, after `dd` exits there is always a delay of about 20 seconds before the data is actually written to the disk.

Many people advocate using the `sync` command after the `dd` command, or including one of the several `sync` options in the `dd` command when writing to a block device. E.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473854/block-device-cache-v-s-a-filesystem) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312687/why-is-sync-so-important-when-making-a-bootable-linux-usb-stick). However, I've not known anyone actually prove that it is necessary.

One of the comments on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal) is:

> `sync` is pointless here [i.e. writing directly to `/dev/sdX`]. It only affects file system operations.

Five people have upvoted this comment and it is consistent with my experience.

So when writing to a block device, are the any circumstances in which `dd` will exit before all writing has completely finished? Has this actually ever happened to anyone?

What about other writing options, such as `cp` and `cat`? Can they exit before writing to a block device has finished?

Comment: @GAD3R: By 'any type of sync' I mean the `sync` command and all `dd`'s sync options.

Comment: According to the man page, `sync` flushes filesystem metadata and cached file data to the underlying filesystem.  When you're dealing with the device directly, there is no "filesystem".  I suspect a `sync` after a `dd` is unnecessary.

Comment: @AndyDalton, that's assuming the man page is technically exact. Is the text there enough to prove that the system doesn't do write caching on block devices?

Comment: @ikkachu No, and that's why I expressed that as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495670/is-it-necessary-to-explicitly-flush-the-hdd-on-disk-write-caches  This Q 8 months ago got no reaction.

Comment: Great question. Please @ me if you ever do get a conclusive answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's about time to answer this.

For such a long time, I've been thinking that only writes to filesystems were cached, not block devices, only to discover that I was wrong : **writes to block devices are cached**.

Strictly speaking I don't have an *official* source on this, and will update my answer as I get one<del>, but you can find some info here : [linux - Block device cache v.s. a filesystem - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473854/block-device-cache-v-s-a-filesystem)</del>. Sorry, I just noticed you saw that question too !

In fact, I had the problem of dd'ing an image to a USB stick, eject it after completion and then discover it was corrupted. It shouldn't have behaved like that since it seems a complete sync is done on the last `close()` on the device, hence I suppose either I got data corruption on my device, or I missed a process that still had the block device opened, but anyway I'm not taking chances any more.

So yes, adding sync options to `dd` when writing to a block device doesn't seem to be an urban legend. I think `conv=fdatasync` should be enough and best performing (no file metadata is added after all, and only syncing at the end of the process is really needed), but the extremists among us may prefer `oflag=sync` (complete data + metadata sync after each write). Check `man 2 open` and `man 2 fdatasync` for more insight.

According to what I've read (but nothing official as of now, unfortunately), `cp` and `cat` to a block device can indeed exit before sync if some other process still has the block device open, unless explicitly requested with some SYNC flags when the device is `open()`ed or with a sync system call such as `fdatasync()`, `fsync()` or more exaggeratingly `sync()`, which none of these commands does...

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/block/bdev.c#L213  bdev.c is where the code it that lets you treat a block device like a file. this is the function that flushes.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been testing something similar and the tellall is the stacktrace on the dd process.

I did a dd directly to the block device (note WITHOUT oflag=direct which
bypasses the page cache) including status=progress and what I get is: the
status will say really quick speeds 187MB/s (as the amount of time to write to the page cache is small) but then dd calls blkdev_close on the block device, and then you wait, and when it finishes, you get the speed based on the total time to write including the flushing on the close call, which is therefore much slower.

```
echo;echo;echo;date; dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M of=/dev/mockdevice status=progress; date

Thu 08 Oct 2020 10:47:36 AM EDT
3172990976 bytes (3.2 GB, 3.0 GiB) copied, 17 s, 187 MB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/mockdevice': No space left on device
3073+0 records in
3072+0 records out
3221225472 bytes (3.2 GB, 3.0 GiB) copied, 1681.94 s, 1.9 MB/s
Thu 08 Oct 2020 11:15:38 AM EDT
```

Here's the stack trace while it's flushing after the dd completes
(in my case, it errored on disk full)

```
cat /proc/1130961/stack
[<0>] __lock_page+0x128/0x230
[<0>] write_cache_pages+0x354/0x4b0
[<0>] generic_writepages+0x57/0x90
[<0>] blkdev_writepages+0xe/0x10
[<0>] do_writepages+0x43/0xd0
[<0>] __filemap_fdatawrite_range+0xd5/0x110
[<0>] filemap_write_and_wait+0x44/0xa0
[<0>] __blkdev_put+0x72/0x1e0
[<0>] blkdev_put+0x4e/0xe0
[<0>] blkdev_close+0x26/0x30
[<0>] __fput+0xcc/0x260
[<0>] ____fput+0xe/0x10
[<0>] task_work_run+0x8f/0xb0
[<0>] exit_to_usermode_loop+0x131/0x160
[<0>] do_syscall_64+0x163/0x190
[<0>] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
```

It's also worth noting that when you fill up the pagecache with dd, the page cache flushing to the block device does so one page at a time.  Filesystems will send bios with lots of pages to flush in one bio, but the page cache flusher in the stacktrace above, only seems to push out one page per bio.

So from this, my experience is that you do not have to call sync, because the blkdev_close actually flushes all dirty cache pages to the block device before it returns and lets dd complete.