# pv gives 100% progress with small buffer

Tags: buffer, pv

I have to do a long task (convert image format) for every file of a folder. I achieved to use `pv` to write the estimation of duration with (used `sleep` here to simulated processing time):

`pv -B 1 =(find . -iwholename '*.png') | xargs -l sh -c 'sleep 0.1'`

I was thinking like there may be an internal buffer which can mess up the estimation, because the list of files itself is not very large (tens of KB) and there may be internal buffer somewhere like in `pv`, so I limited the buffer to 1 byte with `-B 1`. And I wonder if that could cause performance issues (because disk can only read by a minimum of 512 bytes per read, and discard 511 bytes), but I don't know if maybe it resides it memory because `=()` is used. I feel like `-B 1` is a bad solution.

But more importantly, there are strange behaviour with others values for `-B`. For example :

`pv =(yes | head -n 100) -B 1 | xargs -l sh -c 'sleep 1'`

Will work as expected (although starting strangely around `17%` and starting rendering only after a few seconds), but

`pv =(yes | head -n 100) -B 10 | xargs -l sh -c 'sleep 1'`

will print immediately `100%` even if I thought it should take 100 seconds to process, updating at interval of `5%`, because 200 bytes are printed, x100 characters `y` and `\n`. Why ?

**Note** : `=()` requires `zsh`. I tried with `<()` and the progress bar doesn't work. Maybe `pv` can't estimate the fifo size, but it can with a file?

Comment: The output from `pv` is often misleading, when writing via a buffer. When the process has finished writing to the buffer, it has finished according to `pv`, but there might be a slow background process to write from the buffer to the target, for example the memory cells of a USB drive. One way to manage that is to watch flushing the 'dirty' data from the buffer after the `sync` command. I use this method in `mkusb`, and you can grab the shellscript `watch-flush` from there. See also [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554265/).

Comment: The version of `watch-flush` in mkusb is updated (improved) compared to the version in the link from my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

To convert image format for a lot of files, you can let `pv` count the files converted. This is not perfect, because some files take longer time that other files, but it can provide a fair estimate.

Start by counting the total amount of files, something like the following command (my pictures from June this year),

```
$ find 2022/06 \( -name '*.jpg' -or -name '*.png' \)|wc -l
55
```

Then create a command line, that can take advantage of `pv -l -s55`, counting lines. If your converting process does not produce any output, you can add an echo statement (`feh` shows pictures but produces no output to the calling terminal window, so I let echo print only a line feed).

```
$ find 2022/06 -type f -exec bash -c "feh -r -g 1000x1000 --zoom max {} & sleep .5; pkill feh ;sleep .5;echo ''" \; | pv -l -s55 > /dev/null
22,0  0:00:23 [ 978m/s] [==============>                       ] 40% ETA 0:00:34
```

or if you want to see the output scroll, don't redirect the output,

```
$ find 2022/06 -type f -exec bash -c "feh -r -g 1000x1000 --zoom max {} & sleep .5; pkill feh ;sleep .5;echo ''" \; | pv -l -s55
0,00  0:00:01 [0,00 /s] [>                                     ]  0% ETA 0:00:00
1,00  0:00:02 [1,01 /s] [>                                     ]  1% ETA 0:01:48
2,00  0:00:03 [ 984m/s] [>                                     ]  3% ETA 0:01:19
3,00  0:00:04 [ 978m/s] [>                                     ]  5% ETA 0:01:09
4,00  0:00:05 [ 983m/s] [=>                                    ]  7% ETA 0:01:03
5,00  0:00:06 [ 984m/s] [==>                                   ]  9% ETA 0:01:00
6,00  0:00:07 [1,08 /s] [==>                                   ] 10% ETA 0:00:57
7,00  0:00:08 [ 980m/s] [===>                                  ] 12% ETA 0:00:54
8,00  0:00:09 [ 980m/s] [====>                                 ] 14% ETA 0:00:52
9,00  0:00:10 [ 979m/s] [=====>                                ] 16% ETA 0:00:51
10,0  0:00:11 [ 983m/s] [=====>                                ] 18% ETA 0:00:49
11,0  0:00:12 [1,08 /s] [======>                               ] 20% ETA 0:00:48
12,0  0:00:13 [ 982m/s] [======>                               ] 21% ETA 0:00:46
13,0  0:00:14 [ 982m/s] [=======>                              ] 23% ETA 0:00:45
14,0  0:00:15 [ 981m/s] [========>                             ] 25% ETA 0:00:43
15,0  0:00:16 [ 986m/s] [=========>                            ] 27% ETA 0:00:42
16,0  0:00:17 [1,08 /s] [==========>                           ] 29% ETA 0:00:41
17,0  0:00:18 [ 983m/s] [==========>                           ] 30% ETA 0:00:40
18,0  0:00:19 [ 984m/s] [===========>                          ] 32% ETA 0:00:39
19,0  0:00:20 [ 982m/s] [===========>                          ] 34% ETA 0:00:37
20,0  0:00:21 [ 981m/s] [============>                         ] 36% ETA 0:00:36
21,0  0:00:22 [1,08 /s] [=============>                        ] 38% ETA 0:00:35
22,0  0:00:23 [ 985m/s] [==============>                       ] 40% ETA 0:00:34
23,0  0:00:24 [ 983m/s] [==============>                       ] 41% ETA 0:00:33
24,0  0:00:25 [ 981m/s] [===============>                      ] 43% ETA 0:00:32
25,0  0:00:26 [ 986m/s] [================>                     ] 45% ETA 0:00:31
26,0  0:00:27 [ 985m/s] [================>                     ] 47% ETA 0:00:30
27,0  0:00:28 [1,08 /s] [=================>                    ] 49% ETA 0:00:29
28,0  0:00:29 [ 983m/s] [==================>                   ] 50% ETA 0:00:27
29,0  0:00:30 [ 983m/s] [==================>                   ] 52% ETA 0:00:26
30,0  0:00:31 [ 983m/s] [===================>                  ] 54% ETA 0:00:25
31,0  0:00:32 [ 979m/s] [====================>                 ] 56% ETA 0:00:24
32,0  0:00:33 [1,08 /s] [=====================>                ] 58% ETA 0:00:23
33,0  0:00:34 [ 982m/s] [=====================>                ] 60% ETA 0:00:22
34,0  0:00:35 [ 981m/s] [======================>               ] 61% ETA 0:00:21
35,0  0:00:36 [ 980m/s] [======================>               ] 63% ETA 0:00:20
36,0  0:00:37 [ 983m/s] [=======================>              ] 65% ETA 0:00:19
37,0  0:00:38 [1,08 /s] [========================>             ] 67% ETA 0:00:18
38,0  0:00:39 [ 984m/s] [=========================>            ] 69% ETA 0:00:17
39,0  0:00:40 [ 983m/s] [=========================>            ] 70% ETA 0:00:16
40,0  0:00:41 [ 978m/s] [==========================>           ] 72% ETA 0:00:15
41,0  0:00:42 [ 979m/s] [===========================>          ] 74% ETA 0:00:14
42,0  0:00:43 [1,08 /s] [===========================>          ] 76% ETA 0:00:13
43,0  0:00:44 [ 981m/s] [============================>         ] 78% ETA 0:00:12
44,0  0:00:45 [ 981m/s] [=============================>        ] 80% ETA 0:00:11
45,0  0:00:46 [ 985m/s] [=============================>        ] 81% ETA 0:00:10
46,0  0:00:47 [ 983m/s] [==============================>       ] 83% ETA 0:00:09
47,0  0:00:48 [1,08 /s] [===============================>      ] 85% ETA 0:00:08
48,0  0:00:49 [ 983m/s] [================================>     ] 87% ETA 0:00:07
49,0  0:00:50 [ 981m/s] [================================>     ] 89% ETA 0:00:06
50,0  0:00:51 [ 986m/s] [=================================>    ] 90% ETA 0:00:05
51,0  0:00:52 [ 981m/s] [=================================>    ] 92% ETA 0:00:04
52,0  0:00:53 [1,08 /s] [==================================>   ] 94% ETA 0:00:03
53,0  0:00:54 [ 982m/s] [===================================>  ] 96% ETA 0:00:02
54,0  0:00:55 [ 984m/s] [====================================> ] 98% ETA 0:00:01
55,0  0:00:55 [ 982m/s] [====================================>] 100%
```