# dd displays progress incorrectly when writing to flash card (faster than actual)

Tags: dd, flash-memory

I am writing Raspi images on flash card with the following command

```
dd bs=4M if=image.img of=/dev/sdf conv=fsync status=progress
```

and it displays progress

```
5662310400 bytes (5,7 GB, 5,3 GiB) copied, 25 s, 226 MB/s
```

unfortunately, it does full progres in few seconds, while real writing continues several minutes after this. This is evident because `dd` doesn't exit and flash readed LED blinks.

How to make it to display actual progress and/or disable any caching during `dd`?

Comment: Please try `oflag=sync` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is sync so important when making a bootable linux usb stick?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312687/why-is-sync-so-important-when-making-a-bootable-linux-usb-stick)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent dd's progress from being meaningless on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379947/how-to-prevent-dds-progress-from-being-meaningless-on-linux)