# When writing an ISO image to USB flash drive with dd, how do I know I can remove the stick?

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, usb, dd

When writing an ISO image to USB flash drive with `dd`, how do I know I can remove the stick? Obviously I'll wait until the command completes and I'm back at the terminal prompt. But even then the device might still be busy from a cache/buffer. Because I'm writing to the device itself, nothing is mounted, so I also don't call `umount` and cannot see if the device is still busy.

I've seen `dd ... && sync` a few times. But doesn't that block until buffers for *all* media have been written? Not only the one flash drive that I used `dd` with. So if I have lots of other write processes, wouldn't that block?

Would the `conv=` argument for `dd` help? But which one of `conv=sync`, `conv=fsync`, `conv=fdatasync`, ...?

Comment: I think most people use `sync` for this purpose (yes, it flushes all buffers, but that's OK in almost all cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are short descriptions of `fsync` and `fdatasync` in `man dd` and with slightly more details in `info dd`.

If I don't want to use the separate and global `sync`, I would use `conv=fsync` in `dd`because it writes both data and metadata before finishing. From `info dd`:

```
 ‘fdatasync’
      Synchronize output data just before finishing.  This forces a
      physical write of output data.

 ‘fsync’
      Synchronize output data and metadata just before finishing.
      This forces a physical write of output data and metadata.
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the `dd` command has finished, run `sudo eject /dev/sd[drive letter]`. Once that has finished, you are free to remove it. The data will be sync'd.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/312766) to a related question seems to imply that `conv=fdatasync` is equivalent to `sync` for that one `dd` call.

Comment: There are short descriptions of `fsync` and `fdatasync' in `man dd` and with slightly more details in `info dd`.